# Query into the cumulative velocity of mounted platforms

Tags: classical-mechanics, special-relativity, energy, kinematics, velocity

Consider throwing a stone at an object from rest, it travels at Vms-1. Now throw that stone whilst running at Ums-1. It seems in the latter scenario the total speed of stone is V + U. Now imagine Running at Ums-1, throwing a stone at Vms-1 whilst on a moving train with speed Wms-1 - total stone speed would be V+U+W.

Let's extrapolate this to the case where you have a stack of moving platforms, the bottom platform begins to accelerate, once reaching top speed, the platform on top begins to accelerate, and so on and so forth. In a vacuum could it be theoretically possible to reach near infinite projectile velocities using these cumulative platform velocities?

[image]

Comment: hello_there_andy: "_[...] Now throw that stone whilst running at [speed] Ums-1. It seems in the latter scenario the total [speed] of the stone is [(V + U)][ms-1]._" -- Not really. From the detailed definitions of how to determine (compare, "add") "_velocity_" values (which involves detailed definitions of how to determine geometric relations between "starting gate" and "finish line") it follows, that in the indicated scenario the total speed of the stone (wrt. the "race track") "_seems_" (V + U)ms-1 **only as far as** the number "V * U / 300000000^2" is considered negligible.

Comment: I might be having deja vu, but I swear there was a similar problem posted a few months ago with this same exact drawing attached, but I'm having trouble finding it. In general, the answer is "yes, the velocities do add together", or at least in the non-relativistic limit (relativistic speeds are not really a problem here). In reality, there is the additional requirement that the ratio of the $k$th stage's weight is much larger than the $k+1$th stage's weight, in addition to the obvious practical issues with actually building such a device. But the general principle is approximately correct.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus you're not going crazy, it was closed at the time because I asked it more from an engineering/design style... this is more a query about the underlying physics

Comment: @hello_there_andy: Ah, ok, makes sense. But yeah, in short, you're correct that the velocities add together (approximately). That fails once you get to relativistic speeds, but typical rail-gun velocities are between 10000 and 100000 times slower than light, so you can safely ignore relativity.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus DumpsterDoofus: "_That fails once you get to relativistic speeds, but typical rail-gun velocities are between 10000 and 100000 times slower than light, so you can safely ignore relativity_" -- Then let's consider the conservative "$\beta_i := 10^{(-5)}$"; or, as hello_there_andy might put it: "v_i := 3000 _ms-1_". So: What exactly do we tell him about _"Russian Dolls"_ with 100000 or even more such stages ?!? @hello_there_andy -- I remember that drawing (or sth similar?), too. You might find it helpful for now to get rid of any `energy` considerations and focus on `kinematics`.

Comment: @user12262: A railgun with 100,000 stages as drawn in the picture would probably end up being the size of the solar system, so I think the possibility can be ruled out in the near future, given the current state of space research funding :)

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus: "_A railgun with 100,000 stages as drawn would probably end up the size of the solar system, so I think the possibility can be ruled out in the near future, given the current state of space research funding :)_" -- Well, projecting the generally expected rate of proposal maturation h_t_a might instead take steps through the long tail of [thermal distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) and make his scheme fit snugly in the solar core. p.s. Just noticed [jazzwhiz's contribution](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/106669) So: your turn?

Comment: @user12262: So you mean [something like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YU6AuzxUF10)?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus: Didn't bother to watch (sorry). At any rate: eventually, I meant something more like [that](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/106897).

Comment: @user12262: Cool, +1 for taking time to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one formula relating the speeds of any two "*platforms*" (say $P$ and $Q$) between each other:

$$V_{P}[ Q ] = V_{Q}[ P ].$$

And there's of course the well known symbol for "speed of light (in vacuum)", as determined of light signals exchanged by members of any one platform between each other: $c$.

The speed of any one platform ($Q$) as determined by members of any other platform ($P$) can thereby be expressed (and this will be found convenient below) as

$$V_{P}[ Q ] = c \, \, \beta_{P}[ Q ]$$

with the appropriate real number value $\beta_{P}[ Q ]$.

Correspondingly of course:

$$\beta_{P}[ Q ] = \beta_{Q}[ P ].$$

And then there's one formula relating the (pairwise) speeds, or for simplicity rather the corresponding $\beta$-numbers, of any three "*platforms*" (say $G$, $H$, and $J$) between each other:

$$1 - \left( \, \beta_{H}[ G ] \, \, \, \beta_{H}[ J ] \, \, \, \text{Cos}[ \angle_{H}[ G, J ] ] \, \right) = \sqrt{ \frac{(1 - \beta^2_{H}[ G ]) \, (1 - \beta^2_{H}[ J ])}{(1 - \beta^2_{G}[ J ])} }.$$

In case $\text{Cos}[ \angle_{H}[ G, J ] ] = -1$ which should be applicable to the "*stack of platforms*" described in the question this simplifies to the surely familiar formula

$$\beta_{G}[ J ] = \frac{ (\beta_{H}[ G ] + \beta_{H}[ J ]) }{ (1 + \beta_{H}[ G ] \, \, \beta_{H}[ J ]) }, $$

or likewise:

$$\beta_{G}[ J ] = \frac{ (\beta_{G}[ H ] + \beta_{H}[ J ]) }{ (1 + \beta_{G}[ H ] \, \, \beta_{H}[ J ]) }. $$

Now, this formula can be applied to the speed values given in the question
$v_1 := \beta_1 \, c$, $v_2 := \beta_2 \, c$, ... $v_k := \beta_k \, c$ and so on;
where $v_1$ is the speed of the bullet wrt. the first platform, $v_2$ the speed of the second platform wrt. the first, and so on; successively in the proposed "*Russian Doll*" setup.

Of particular interest are surely the resulting speed value $V_{[0, k]}$ (or the corresponding real number $\beta_{[0, k]}$) of the bullet wrt. the $k$<sup>th</sup> platform.

With the above formula follows

$$ \beta_{[0, (k + 1)]} = \frac{ (\beta_{[0, k]} + \beta_k) }{ (1 + \beta_{[0, k]} \, \, \beta_k) } $$

Noting the similarity of this formula to the [addition theorem of the "hyperbolic tangent" function $\text{Tanh}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_tangent#Identities),

$$\text{Tanh}[ x + y ] = \frac{ (\text{Tanh}[ x ] + \text{Tanh}[ y ]) }{ (1 + \text{Tanh}[ x ] \, \, \text{Tanh}[ y ]) },$$

we obtain

$$ \beta_{[0, (k + 1)]} = \text{Tanh}[ \text{ArcTanh}[ \beta_{[0, k ]} ] + \text{ArcTanh}[ \beta_k ] ]$$.

Applying this to all ("$n$") given speed values (or corresponding $\beta$ values) then

$$ \beta_{[0, n]} = \text{Tanh}[ \sum^n_{j = 1} \text{ArcTanh}[ \beta_j ] ], $$

or correspondingly

$$ V_{[0, n]} = c \, \, \text{Tanh}[ \sum^n_{j = 1} \text{ArcTanh}[ \frac{v_j}{c} ] ]. $$

The values of the $\text{Tanh}$ function are or course approching $1$, but don't reach the value $1$ for any argument value; cmp. http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sinh%2Bcosh%2Btanh.svg

Therefore the total bullet speed (wrt. the "final, $n$<sup>th</sup>  platform") that may be reached in the described "*Russian Doll*" setup with $n$ successive platforms cannot reach (or even exceed) the speed of light, $c$.

Answer (score 1):

There are two formulas for adding velocities. The first is typically called [Galilean relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula#Galilean_addition_of_velocities) and the second [special relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula#Special_theory_of_relativity). The first is simple, if you stack your tank on top of a train then the speed of the shell is the sum of the velocities, $v_1+v_2$. These things can be added as much as you like. You have an aircraft carrier moving at $v_1$ respect to the water which launches a plane at speed $v_2$ with respect to the carrier. The plane then immediately launches a rocket with speed $v_3$ with respect to the plane. The rocket thingy would be going $v_1+v_2+v_3$ with respect to the water.

The second is more complicated. Einstein said that nothing goes faster than the speed of light, $c$. Of course, this runs into problems if the speeds above are comparable to the speed of light, because then you might go over. Einstein showed (among other things) that speeds don't *quite* add in this simple sense. The speed addition formula that comes out of special relativity is
$$\frac{v_1+v_2}{1+\frac{v_1v_2}{c^2}}$$
The first thing we can do is check at what speeds this is the same as Galilean relativity. Of course if one of the speeds is zero they are exactly the same. If they are non-zero then they are never the same, but may be very close. For example, for two objects traveling at 10% the speed of light, Galilean relativity says that together they travel at 20% the speed of light while special relativity says that they travel at 19.802% the speed of light. So Galilean relativity is wrong by about 1%. In general, if the speeds are each about $\beta=v/c$ then the error between the two approaches is about $\beta^2$ for $\beta\lesssim0.1$. This is a rule of thumb of course, but a pretty good starting point. For example, according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_1#Exit_from_the_heliosphere) Voyager 1 is moving away from the sun faster than any other human made object. Its speed relative to the sun is $1.7\times10^4$ m/s or $\beta=5.667\times10^{-5}c$, so every macroscopic thing (that you can pick up and throw or larger) on earth is traveling at speeds slow enough that relativity will not noticeably affect its dynamics.